# HUE File Manager, able to create HDFS subdirectory/folder but unable to upload file to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, amazon-emr, hue

I am getting an:

`Error: Undefined message` in HUE every time I try to upload a file.
I am able to create a subdirectory/folder in HDFS but file uploads are not working.

I tried copying a file to HDFS from the linux CLI using the hadoop user, and it works.

Hue user is `hadoop`

HDFS directory owner is `hadoop:hadoop`

**Edit:** Adding the error

```
ERROR    Internal Server Error: /filebrowser/upload/file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 300, in process_view
    request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 126, in _get_post
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/http/request.py", line 299, in _load_post_and_files
    self._post, self._files = self.parse_file_upload(self.META, data)
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/http/request.py", line 258, in parse_file_upload
    return parser.parse()
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 269, in parse
    self._close_files()
  File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.20-py2.7.egg/django/http/multipartparser.py", line 316, in _close_files
    handler.file.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

[12/Apr/2020 22:48:51 -0700] upload       DEBUG    HDFSfileUploadHandler receive_data_chunk

[12/Apr/2020 22:48:51 -0700] upload       ERROR    Not using HDFS upload handler: 

[12/Apr/2020 22:48:51 -0700] resource     ERROR    All 1 clients failed: {'http://IRedactedMyinstanceIdentHere.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:14000/webhdfs/v1': u'500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://IRedactedMyinstanceIdentHere.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/Test-Data?op=CHECKACCESS&fsaction=rw-&user.name=hue&doas=hadoop\n{"RemoteException":{"message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.client.HttpFSFileSystem.Operation.CHECKACCESS","exception":"QueryParamException","javaClassName":"com.sun.jersey.api.ParamException$QueryParamException"}}\n'}

[12/Apr/2020 22:48:51 -0700] resource     ERROR    Caught exception from http://IRedactedMyinstanceIdentHere.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:14000/webhdfs/v1: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://IRedactedMyinstanceIdentHere.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/Test-Data?op=CHECKACCESS&fsaction=rw-&user.name=hue&doas=hadoop
{"RemoteException":{"message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.client.HttpFSFileSystem.Operation.CHECKACCESS","exception":"QueryParamException","javaClassName":"com.sun.jersey.api.ParamException$QueryParamException"}}
 (error 500)
```

Comment: Do you see any error in hue logs?

Comment: Added the error in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error message, it reports that there is no match found for the query param passed when hue tries to perform the `CHECKACCESS` operation.

```
http://IRedactedMyinstanceIdentHere.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/Test-Data?op=CHECKACCESS&fsaction=rw-&user.name=hue&doas=hadoop

{"RemoteException":{"message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.client.HttpFSFileSystem.Operation.CHECKACCESS","exception":"QueryParamException","javaClassName":"com.sun.jersey.api.ParamException$QueryParamException"}}
```

This implementation seems to be missing in some of the hadoop versions and is a known bug [HTTPFS - CHECKACCESS operation missing](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-9695).

Comment: How do I apply the patch?

Comment: Not sure whether we can apply patches from apache-hadoop distribution to amazon-emr's hadoop as this may have unintended issues. Suggest you contact Amazon support to report this bug.

Comment: Thank you! I've opened a ticket with Amazon.